# Mirror/Copy/Update one table to a different database in another table - ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle, populate

I have two identical databases deployed on two servers, and I want to update/mirror on the table from one DB to the other.

eg. One table, dbName1.Cars to be updated on dbName2.Cars. Is there a way to add some Job or Scheduler on dbName1 which should populate the dbName2?

I'm using ORACLE Databases.

Comment: This problem can resolve by GoldenGate. But this for DBA. 
For developer: Database link and Materialized view

Comment: Why bother duplicating at all?  Just create db links between the dbs, and allow one database to query the table in the other database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have two databases, you'll need a **database link** so - simplified - you'd

```
insert into cars@db_link select * from cars;
```

If you put such a code into a **stored procedure**, you can schedule its execution using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` (or `DBMS_JOB`) package and make it run anytime you want (e.g. at 2:30 after midnight, at 10:30 in the morning ..., every day / once a week / only during weekend ...).

---

Or, create a **materialized view**. Simplified, again:

```
create materialized view mv_cars as select * from cars@db_link;
```

It lets you schedule refreshing intervals from *on demand* (you explicitly say "refresh, now!") to other options Oracle supports.

---

Also, read about [Golden Gate](https://www.oracle.com/integration/goldengate/) and [Advanced Replication](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REPLN/toc.htm). These options aren't that trivial, though.